# How to build war using maven in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, war

That is pretty easy in **Ultimate** Itellij Idea.

In **community** version I have the following problems:

1. I can't open maven **lifecycle** window.
2. When I right click on **pom.xml** and choose **Maven** I see only [image]
3. Using artifacts + build it's impossible to choose **.war** [image]

It's worth saying that I have mvn project and I need to create .war from one of the **subprojects**

Comment: You can run Maven goals from the Maven tool window in IntelliJ IDEA. If you can build it from the command line, you can do the same from the IDE.

Comment: @RobertoManfreda packaging tag is needed to specify a type but It doesn't build anything

Comment: @CrazyCoder could you clarify which steps should I perform? Should I install maven to build the project with maven in intellij?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html. Maven is bundled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you can't enable the Maven Tool window?

I'm using the Community Edition (2018.3, so not the latest one) and the Maven tool window is available (appears by default on the right), see below:

[image: Maven tool window]

If you can't find it, try ***View/Tool Windows/Maven***

Comment: You are right but it was not by default opened on the right side as in ultimate. I tried to find It in Tools tab but it is in View/Windows Tools tab

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve doing cmd into your project root folder and run the maven goal `mvn clean install or mvn clean package`

Before that make sure you define your project with as packaging of war type and also check you have maven installed and set maven [home](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm)

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```